# Java error! haven't seen solution elsewhere

Tags: java

I am writing a program that will allow the credit and debit of purchases with one retailer and multiple buyers.  After each buyer has purchased or made pmnt, I need each transaction in a monthly summary.
Here is what I have, the only error I have at this point is:

```
Main.java:136: error: not a statement
                  displayprocestran;   
                  ^
Main.java:144: error: not a statement
                displayprostrans;
                ^
```

This is the program:

```
/*Project4B, Judith Berk, CIS 2110, 4/28/13*/

import java.io.*;

public class Project4BDriver 
{

    public void main(String args[]) throws IOException ;
    {
         Project4B app;
         app = new Project4B();
         app.appMain();
    }
} //end of class DriverProject4B

class Project4B 
{
     //Data declarations

     BufferedReader stdin;
     String custName;
     char transType;
     int transNum;
     float transAmt;
     float prcnt;
     float prcntChrg;
     float TprcntChrg;
     float runBal;
     float begBal;
     float endBal;
     float TPmnt;
     float TChrg;
     int PurchCtr;
     float HiPurchAmt;
     String HiPurchCust;
     float AvgPurch;
     float CoMonthBal;
     float CoTnewChrg;
     float CoTPmnt;
     float CobegBal;


    public void appMain() throws IOException ;
    {
        outputHeader();
        initReport();
        getAcctInfo();
        initrunBal();

        while (transNum != 0);
        {
             prostrans();
        }

         calculate average;
         calculate runBal;
         calculate interest;
         display summary;
    }

    void outputHeader();
    {
         //Output report header
         System.out.print("^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^\n");
         System.out.println("Project4B");
         System.out.println("Judith Berk CIS 2110");
         System.out.println("Supply Chain Monthly Report");
         System.out.print("^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^\n");
    }

    void initReport() 
    {
         //standard input will be keyboard
         stdin = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader.System.in());

         TPmnt = 0;
         TChrg = 0;
         PurchCtr = 0;
         PrcntChrg = 0;
         TprcntChrg = 0;
         hiPurchAmt = 0;
         CoMonthlyBal = 0;
    }

    public void getAcctInfo() throws IOException;
    {
         System.out.print("Please enter CUSTOMER NAME:");
         custName = (stdin.readLine());

         System.out.print("Please enter BEGINNING BALANCE for Customer:");
         begBal = Float.parseFloat(stdin.readLine());

         System.out.print("Please enter Customer's individual INTEREST RATE (i.e. 0.05, 0.03, 0.035):");
         prcnt = Float.parseFloat(stdin.readLine());
    }

    void initrunBal()

    {
         runBal = begBal;
    }

    public void prostrans() throws IOException;

    {
         get transNum;
    }

    public void gettransNum() throws IOException;

    {
         System.out.print("Please enter TRANSACTION NUMBER:");
         transNum = Integer.ParseInt(stdin.readLine());
    }

    public void gettransDetails() throws IOException;

    {
         System.out.print("Please enter TRANSACTION AMOUNT:");
         transAmt = Float.parseFloat(stdin.readLine());

         System.out.print("Please enter TRANSACTION TYPE:");
         transType = (stdin.readLine().charAt(0));
    }

    void  calcTPmntTChrgTPrcntChrgandrunBal();
    {

         if ((transType == "C") && (transType ==  "c"))
           {
                 purchCtr = purchCtr + 1;
                 prcntChrg = prcnt * transAmt;
                 runBal = runBal + transAmt + prcntChrg;
                 TChrg = TChrg + transAmt;
                 TprcntChrg = prcntChrg + prcntChrg;
                  displayprocestran;   
            } 


         else if ((transType == "p") && (transType ==  "P"))
            {
                 runBal = runBal - transAmt;
                 TPmnt = TPmnt + transAmt;
                displayprostrans;
            }



    }

    void displayprostran();
    {
         System.out.println("*\n" + custName);
         System.out.println("*\n" + transAmt);
         System.out.println("*\n" + runBal);
    }

    void updateHiPurchCustandHiPurchTot();
    {
        if (HiPurchAmt > TChrg);
            {
                 HiPurchChrg = TChrge;
                 HiPurchName = custName;
            }
    }

    void calcAvgPurch();
    {
         AvgPurch = TChrg / purchCtr;
    }

    void initCoMonthBal()
    {
         get CobegBal;
    }

    {
         System.out.print("Enter Company Beginning Balance");
         CobegBal = Float.parseFloat(stdin.readLine());
    }

    void calcCosummary();
    {
         CoMonthBal = CobegBal + TChrg - TPmnt;
    }

    void displaysummary()
    {
         System.out.print("Customer Name:\t" + custName);
         System.out.print("Customer Beginning Balance:\t" + begBal);
         System.out.print("Customer Payments:\t" + TPmnt);
         System.out.print("Customer New Charges:\t" + TChrg);
         System.out.print("Customer Interest Charge:\t" + TprcntChrg);
         System.out.print("Customer Ending balance:\t" + runBal);

         System.out.print("Overall Company Ending Balance:\t" + CoMonthlBal);
         System.out.print("Monthly Average Purchases:\t" + AvgChrg);
         System.out.print("Monthly Payments Received:\t" + TPmnts);
         System.out.print("Customer with highest monthly Purchases:\t" + HiPurchName);
         System.out.print("Highest Monthly Purchase Amount:\t" + HiPurchAmt);
    }
}
```

Please help me!

Thanks Judy

Comment: Argh, do not store money as floats.

Comment: `displayprostrans;` is not a statement.  Also, @MK is completely right - don't use floats for money, they're not even close to accurate enough for financial matters.

Comment: The variable `transType` is a `char`; compare to the character literals `'C'` and `'c'`.  In addition, it can't be both `'C'` and `'c'`.  I suspect that you meant "or", so use `||` instead of `&&`.

Answer (score 6):

---

#### Your problem

---

```
 displayprocestran;
```

Is most definitely not a statement. Perhaps you mean

```
  displayprocestran();
```

---

#### Side note on Error messages

---

At first, error messages might seem a little cryptic, but let's look at your's.

```
 Main.java:136: error: not a statement displayprocestran;
Main.java:144: error: not a statement displayprostrans; ^
```

Well, it's telling you that it found the error where the `^` points to, which is at the end of `displayprocestran`. It's also telling you this is not a statement. This should tell you, that you have a syntax error, which means you've typed it wrong. Now, you call methods like `stdin.readLine()` all over the place. You should start to try and make the link as to *why* you're getting these errors.

---

#### Other things I've noticed that I haven't seen mentioned already

---

**Naming**

Well, I guess the big one is how unreadable your methods are. The [Java naming conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconv-138413.html) explain how methods and variables should be laid out. For example:

```
displayprocestran --- > displayProcesTran (I think)
```

**Encapsulation**

You've got methods like:

```
void initrunBal()
{
     runBal = begBal;
}
```

I'm not sure when the user will need to use this method. So perhaps making it's access modifier `private`. This is about ensuring that the interface presented to users of your classes, are just the methods that they need. They don't need to know about the inner workings of your class. That's called [abstraction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstraction).

**Stuff that simply won't compile**

```
public void prostrans() throws IOException;
{
     get transNum;
}
```

That isn't valid Java. I'm not actually sure what you want from that. Perhaps you want to return `transNum`? In which case, it should be:

```
public int getTransNum()
{
    return transNum;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in the following code:

```
 if ((transType == "C") && (transType ==  "c"))
   {
         ...
         displayprocestran;   
    }
```

are you actually trying to invoke the `void displayprostran()` method?  if so, call it like this

```
 if ((transType == "C") && (transType ==  "c"))
   {
         ...
         displayprostran();   
    }
```